# How do I launch Confluence developer instead of Jira for Plugin?

Tags: plugins, confluence, jira-plugin, confluence-rest-api

I am trying to create a plugin for the Confluence Platform.
When I run `atlas-run` it will launch JIRA.

How do I specify I want to create a plugin for Confluence to test under?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, didn't realize they had this script: `atlas-create-confluence-plugin`